# Angularjs Ionic - Different layouts for mobile and tablets

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile application using **Ionic and angularjs and Highcharts**. In most of the pages there are sliders to display data. Every slide has two vertical divs containing highchart.

Now the requirement of the app is that when it is open in mobile device(Iphone 4 & 5) it should display one div per slide and when open on tablet(Ipad) it should display two vertical divs per slide containing highchart.

I have 10 charts to show. in Iphone/mobile there will be 10 slides(1 chart per slide). and in Tablet/Ipad will have 5 slides(2 chart per slide). 
All the Highchart data is dynamic.

I am posting html code. As for angularJs I am not sure What approach I should take? I have posted image links of screenshots of the desired layouts for both the devices.

[screenshot for Ipad/tablets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vnxl.png)

[screenshot for Iphone/Mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaNHW.png)

**Html**

```
 <ion-view>
  <div ng-controller="chartHomePage">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-slide-box  show-pager="false" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" >
        <ion-slide>
          <div class="card chart-box">
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Chart 1
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
              <div ng-controller="ChartController1">
                <highchart id="" config="chart1"></highchart>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card chart-box">
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Chart 2
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
              <div ng-controller="ChartController2">
                <highchart id="" config="chart2"></highchart>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <iom-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>
  </div><!--end controller div-->
</ion-view>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd think something along the lines of modifying the platform css would do the trick. Try calculating the needed vh and update the .platform-ipad .chart-box class in the css